# How to write builder (transformer) and use it in build_runner

Tags: angular, dart

I want to transform some asset in build release process for my angular application when call:

```
pub run build_runner build --config release --output build
```

I found the doc [Writing a Pub Transformer](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers)

1. What steps different in write builder process?
2. Where should I call my builder and how control build order?

Is it right place **build.release.yaml**?

```
targets:
  $default:
    sources:
      - lib/**
      - web/**
    builders:
      call_my_builder
      build_web_compilers|entrypoint:
        generate_for:
        - web/**.dart
        options:
          compiler: dart2js
          dart2js_args:
          - --fast-startup
          - --minify
          - --trust-type-annotations
          - --trust-primitives
```

---

- angular 5.0.0-alpha+8
- dart 2.0.0-dev.36.0

Comment: Transformers are deprecated and only a subset of transformers are supported by `build`. Build a builder instead https://github.com/dart-lang/build. https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable is a prominent example

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have a progress with builder. One thing left. How to recognize build mode?

Comment: add `--config=release`

Comment: Yes. But what property should I use in builder?